# SQL query to join values from multiple records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, pivot

I've got a table Employees with employees (say the important fields are ID int, Name varchar(50)) and a table Areas with sales areas (ID int, EmployeeID int, USState char(2)).

The sample values are:

```
Employees
ID     Name
1      Shoeman
2      Smith
3      Johnson

Areas
ID     EmployeeID     USState
1      1              NY
2      1              FL
3      1              AR
4      2              DC
5      2              AR
6      3              TX
```

Can anyone give me a hint on making a SQL query to get the output recordset in the following way:

```
EmployeeID     USState
1              NY FL AR
2              DC AR
3              TX
```

Target platform: SQL Server 2005.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This operation is called [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) in MySQL but SQL Server doesn't support it.

In SQL Server you can simulate the same functionality using the [FOR XML PATH](http://blog.shlomoid.com/2008/11/emulating-mysqls-groupconcat-function.html) hack.

```
SELECT extern.EmployeeID, states AS USState
FROM Areas AS extern
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT USState + ' '
    FROM Areas AS intern
    WHERE extern.EmployeeID = intern.EmployeeID
    FOR XML PATH('')
) T1 (states)
GROUP BY extern.EmployeeID, states
ORDER BY extern.EmployeeID
```

An alternative is to use a [recursive CTE](http://explainextended.com/2010/06/21/group_concat-in-sql-server/). This is a less hacky solution but it is also more complicated:

```
WITH qs(EmployeeID, USState, rn, cnt) AS
(
    SELECT
        EmployeeID,
        USState,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeID ORDER BY USState),
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeID)
    FROM    Areas
),
t (EmployeeID, prodname, gc, rn, cnt) AS
(
    SELECT EmployeeID, USState, CAST(USState AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), rn, cnt
    FROM qs
    WHERE rn = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        qs.EmployeeID, qs.USState,
        CAST(t.gc + ' ' + qs.USState AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),
        qs.rn, qs.cnt
    FROM t
    JOIN qs ON qs.EmployeeID = t.EmployeeID
           AND qs.rn = t.rn + 1
)
SELECT EmployeeID, gc AS USState
FROM   t
WHERE  rn = cnt
ORDER BY EmployeeID
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Both methods give the result you want:

```
EmployeeID     USState
1              NY FL AR 
2              DC AR 
3              TX
```

Comment: I like CTE, but till now no time used recursive CTE. Thanks for an interesting example of this!

Answer (score 1):

This is my perfered format to use a UDF (appears to be much faster as well on a large DB)

```
CREATEFUNCTION dbo.StateList(@ID int) RETURNS varchar(max)

AS

DECLARE @out varchar(max);

SET @out=''; -- comment this out to reutrn NULL if nothing found

SELECT @out=@out+USState+' ' -- operates like a loop assigning the values in sequence to the out variable.

FROM AREAS
WHERE EmployeeID=@ID
ORDER BY USState

RETURN @out
```

Query example ...

```
SELECT Name, dbo.StateList(EmployeeID)
FROM Employees
Order BY Name
```

In this manner you create one UDF for each list you wish to explode in this way.